# How to fix "Filesystem.vmdk not found" VMware with COSMOS

Tags: c#, vmware, cosmos

When I try to run an os I have build with cosmos on VMWare, I get the error "Filesystem.vmdk not found". Where do I find this file?

Answer (score 0):

The file should be located at "C:\Users*You*\AppData\Roaming\Cosmos User Kit\Build\VMware\Workstation"